# Bounded Contexts Rules Orchestration

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, business-rules

My banking core domain has divided into 2 distincts bounded contexts BC1 and BC2. These BCs deal with very specific business rules and processes (custom agreement for debt recovery, and administrative indebtedness with legal obligations). BC1 and BC2 are accessed through WebServices from a CRM. A client can't have both a custom agreement and an indebtedness plan, and each situation exclude the other one. So we need to orchestrate both types of processes (more precisely we need to enforce in each BC that actions are permitted, on both sides).

How would you orchestrate them ? Would you inject a bit of knowledge of BC1 in BC2 domain model, and vice-versa, or do you think we should rely on a third BC (BC3) that could orchestrate the system, and would be aware of both business knowledges, and through a third WebService for instance ? We just need to know if the client has an agreement with the company, or if it is officially and legaly indebted.

Do you think having BC1 to know "a little" of BC2 business is violating DDD principles ? In case of an orchestrator or a proxy, would you use WebServices, or SharedKernel ? What are the pros and cons of SharedKernel versus WebServices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of having a BC is to keeps things separated. BC1 and BC2 are strangers. If they share the language they should be one BC. Neither BC needs to know "little" or more about the other. Also querying another BC is just asking for trouble later.

Both BC may communicate via Domain Events. When one BC changes a Domain event (DTO) is published and the other BC can handle it, storing locally (inside its BC) what data it needs (in your case it means storing if a client has custom agreement/indebtedness plan or other things required by that BC to do its work). This way, each BC only works with it's own model only and it's autonomous.

Treating a BC as a remote service is undesirable, because you just couple BC1 to BC2 and it hurts maintainability, performance, availability and scalability.

Comment: I think it depends on the intended use of the BC. For example, a supporting/generic sub-system (Identity and Access). Clearly this type of BC is not meant to exist on a deserted island, but rather provide services to any downstream clients.

Comment: @Marco Things like identity and access and other generic infrastructural components, have little to do with the Domain, they're a part of the application layer.  The OP has a Domain modelling  problem, because it needs business rules from different BCs

Comment: This is not true. BC is just like separate app and there are no contraindications to call external app from your app. Read chapter about Relationships Between Bounded Contexts in DDD. There are many patterns for communication between BC: shared kernel, customer/supplier,  conformist, ACL etc.

Comment: @RafałŁużyński "BC is just like separate app and there are no contraindications to call external app from your app" Hmm... no. I don't need to read chapters, I have practical experience.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you just want to query one BC from another to make sure if some action can be permitted?

It is common to call another services from another BC, just like using external API.
So I would do it that way.

Comment: I wouldn't. See my answer.